# Map mismatched type

Tags: c++

I have a map of type

```
typedef std::map<InterfacePortPath, InterfacePortPath, InterfacePortPathKeyComp> InterfacePortMap;
```

however at one point in code insert is called on this map with

```
.insert(std::make_pair (InterfacePortPath, InterfacePortPath))
```

and it result in the error

```
no matching function for call to 'std::map<InterfacePortPath, InterfacePortPath, InterfacePortPathKeyComp>::insert(std::pair<InterfacePortPath, InterfacePortPath>)'
```

it seems a bit strange because the types seems correct to me.

Edit: makepair is std::make_pair

Comment: What is `makepair`?

Comment: The mapped type is `std::pair<const Key, T>` but the key in the pair you're trying to insert is not `const`

Comment: @perivesta you are right, one way to resolve this is to cast the pair with Key to pair with const key std::pair<const Key, T> = makepair(...), however is there a way to it without making an addtional variable? i.e. doing that in the insert.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Can't reproduce, either `.insert(std::make_pair(...))` works fine for me, regardless of whether the 1st value is `const` or not.  The map will make it `const` when inserted.